# Need to fix the dark shaded polygon

Tags: mesh

[image]

Need to fix the dark shaded polygon. All the plates are clear  but only one is not fixed. Any quick solution for this. tried to fix by applying smooth

Comment: maybe right click > Shade Flat?

Comment: This appears to be a normals issue. Turn on auto-smooth, clear custom split normals data, or shade flat (tried in that order) and see if it helps.